# countdown timer on alert box in android

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog, countdowntimer

How do i display a countdown timer in my alert box .i want to notify the user that the session will end in 5 minutes and show a timer running in the alert pop up box in android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a Custom dialog with a `TextView` on it.

and update that code with the help of `CountDownTimer` class like this.

```
new CountDownTimer(300000, 1000) {

     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
         mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
     }

     public void onFinish() {
         mTextField.setText("done!");
     }
  }.start();
```

you can dismiss your dialog in `onFinish()`.

for more detail you can [follow this link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html)

Comment: @saravanan yeah use custom dialog for that

Comment: its a alert box object in the object.setMessage("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000); its correct or not tell me please

Comment: i dont think its right i would suggest you to use custom dialog box

Comment: @saravanan follow this link for custom dialog http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomDialog

Answer (score 4):

The following code creates a prompt as you described. It adds a count down timer to a default action button.

[image: screenshot of dialog with countdown]
**Dialog Listener Class**

```
private static class DialogTimeoutListener
        implements DialogInterface.OnShowListener, DialogInterface.OnDismissListener {
    private static final int AUTO_DISMISS_MILLIS = 5 * 60 * 1000;
    private CountDownTimer mCountDownTimer;

    @Override
    public void onShow(final DialogInterface dialog) {
        final Button defaultButton = ((AlertDialog) dialog).getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE);
        final CharSequence positiveButtonText = defaultButton.getText();
        mCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(AUTO_DISMISS_MILLIS, 100) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                if (millisUntilFinished > 60000) {
                    defaultButton.setText(String.format(
                            Locale.getDefault(), "%s (%d:%02d)",
                            positiveButtonText,
                            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished),
                            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished % 60000)
                    ));
                } else {
                    defaultButton.setText(String.format(
                            Locale.getDefault(), "%s (%d)",
                            positiveButtonText,
                            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) + 1 //add one so it never displays zero
                    ));
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                if (((AlertDialog) dialog).isShowing()) {
                    // TODO: call your logout method
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
        };
        mCountDownTimer.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
        mCountDownTimer.cancel();
    }
```

**Alert Dialog**

```
AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setTitle("Session Timeout")
        .setMessage("Due to inactivity, you will soon be logged out.")
        .setPositiveButton("Extend Session", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO: call your log out method
            }
        })
        .setNegativeButton("Log Out Now", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO: call method to extend session
            }
        })
        .create();
DialogTimeoutListener listener = new DialogTimeoutListener();
dialog.setOnShowListener(listener);
dialog.setOnDismissListener(listener);
dialog.show();
```